# Problem with Using chntpw in Ubuntu to reset Windows 7 Password

Tags: 11.10

I tried resetting the password of windows 7 Using `chntpw` command in Ubuntu . It showed success. But when I try to login from Windows it does not seem to be changed.

I first used live USB of Ubuntu 11.10 and did **Try Ubuntu**. Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get install chntpw
```

And then:

```
cd /media/Vista/Windows/System32/config
sudo chntpw -u username sam
```

I followed [these instructions](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/resetwindowspasswordold/) and got success like this:

```
Hives that have changed:
# Name
0 <sam>
Write hive files? (y/n) [n] : y
0 <sam> – OK .
```

But when I try to login to windows with blank password, I could not log in.

I also tried changing the password and showed success but I could not log in with that password.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of chntpw](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156833/usage-of-chntpw)

Comment: Rather use [Offline registry editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/).

Comment: Reviewers: when this question was asked, 11.10 was **on topic**.

Answer (score 8):

The 0.99.6 version of chntpw is totally disfunctional: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chntpw/+bug/1046622

I struggled more than a hour to find this out.

Try to use 0.99.5 instead, it works for me:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/i386/chntpw/0.99.5-0+nmu1

Comment: 1.00 seems dysfunctional as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was using `chntpw` to unlock the administrator account, which was the only function of `chntpw` that worked. Then I booted windows, logged in as Administrator, and cleared the users' password with the users app in control panel.

Comment: I have the same observation: chntpw (regardless of version) does not work on regular user accounts, but you *can* use it to unlock the Administrator, after which you can log in that way and change the user account.

Answer (score 1):

To change Administrator password: `sudo chntpw SAM`.
To change another users password: `sudo chntpw -u <your-username> SAM`
Please note the Upper-case of the word SAM

Comment: When I tried using upper-case it showed some errors regarding the heive . So I used lowercase . I tried using both sudo chntpw sam and sudo chntpw -u username sam . It shows success also . But when I log in to windows it says incorrect password . Thank you .

Comment: How do you type your username if it contains accented letters? It's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of chntpw doesn't work with windows 7.  You have to go back a version.

Comment: Can you specify the versions you are talking about?

Comment: 1.00 was failing, but 0.99.6 worked.

Answer (score -1):

I am using Ubuntu 12 and chntpw 0.99.5. I have successfully reset my forgotten password by following [this guide](http://www.chntpw.com/reset-windows-7-admin-password-with-ubuntu/). If there are multiply Windows systems installed on your hard drive, make sure you choose the desired SAM database.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: There is no problem with the steps that Sandesh did. Only the version of chntpw will make difference. chntpw 0.99.5 works from my side.

Comment: Then it sounds like your answer is a duplicate of the top-voted answer already here.