# Unable to change password Using chntpw in Ubuntu to reset Windows 7 Password

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem with Using chntpw in Ubuntu to reset Windows 7 Password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162267/problem-with-using-chntpw-in-ubuntu-to-reset-windows-7-password)

i have followed all the steps given for chntpw. have used all the tutorials i can find including sudo chntpw sam and sudo chntpw -u sam. and i still cannot get the windows 7 password to change.  i have even gone through all 4 options chntpw gives you but still a no go on any type of password reset or change. PLEASE HELP.
using ubuntu 12.04lts.

All of my outputs show successful. getting no errors.

this is one of the tutorials i used http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14369/change-or-reset-windows-password-from-a-ubuntu-live-cd/ 
i followed all the steps and got the same outputs showing that it was successful.

i tried a few other tutorials that were 99% identical with all the same outputs but it still will not let me log in without the original password

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific.  What, exactly, are the steps you followed?  Can you post the output (if any) of chntpw?  Without more info I don't know whether you're doing it wrong or if it's genuinely not working.

Comment: did a test run with xp and it worked fine using the same steps im trying for the windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

I've done the same using BackTrack 3 to clear Windows XP 64-bit and Server 2003 passwords. It is pretty straightforward, as long as you don't forget to save, and probably need to lock the account after clearing password to make sure it is enabled.

There are plenty of video tutorials on Youtube, for example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emXP1eE9hUo

Answer (score 0):

Try with http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Burn it or copy to a USB. Boot and the follow the instructions to reset the password (it's better if you try to remove the password, boot on Windows and change the password using Windows.